# How to update the useState in the promise function of the react js

Tags: reactjs, use-state

As I want to update the products array loaded from the API in the useState but as I update it shows me the error in the console but it works I want to solve that error

```
const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);
const [productslist, setproductslist] = useState([]);
const currentSlug = useParams();
const BrandWiseProduct = () => {
    setloading(true);
    api.get(`brand/${currentSlug.slug}/`).then((response) => {
        setproductslist(response.data);
    });
    setloading(false);
};

const ProductCardRender = productslist.map((product, index) => {
    return (
        <ProductCard
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price}
            key={product.id}
            slug={product.slug}
            image={product.card_banner}
        />
    );
});
```

This is the code and here is the screenshot of the error
[image]
[image]

If there is any better way then please suggest to me you can share any article or blog post.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually, might be able to do it like this:

```
import { useEffect, Suspense } from "react";

const ProductCardRender = () => {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);
  const [productslist, setproductslist] = useState([]);
  const currentSlug = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const BrandWiseProduct = () => {
      setloading(true);
      api.get(`brand/${currentSlug.slug}/`).then((response) => {
        setproductslist(response.data);
      });
      setloading(false);
    };
    BrandWiseProduct();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
      {productslist.map((product, index) => (
        <ProductCard
          name={product.name}
          price={product.price}
          key={product.id}
          slug={product.slug}
          image={product.card_banner}
        />
      ))}
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: any code example for help

Comment: Changed it up a bit.

Comment: Ok bro i will try it